# SQL Update from a Selection + Where condition on this Selection

Tags: sql, sql-update

I would like to do something like this:

```
With T2 as (
    Select * 
    From TABLE t
    Where t.a1=2
)
Update T1
  Set T1.X = T2.X
  Where T1.Y = T2.Y
;
```

I found a solution by putting a selection in the `update`'s `From` clause, but still I need to create my `Where` condition.
So an alternative of what I would like to do is:

```
Update T1
  Set T1.X = T2.X
  From (
    Select * 
    From TABLE t
    Where t.Z=2
  ) T1
  Where T1.Y = T2.Y
;
```

That is theory, and in practice both of my examples don't work.
How can I do that?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent a database specification, you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
    set x = (select t2.x from table t2 where t2.y = t.y and t2.z = 2);
```

This should work in any database, assuming that the subquery does not return multiple rows (if that is the case, you can add `fetch first 1 row only`, `limit`, `top` or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what You are looking for:

```
update TABLE
    set X = t.X
from TABLE T1
    join (select * from TABLE T2 where T2.a1=2) t on t.Y=T1.Y
where T1.Z=2
```